# Upload file into Spark API endpoint

Tags: javascript, java, rest, fetch, spark-java

I'm trying to upload a file to a Spark Api with and enpoint like the following:

```
after((Filter) (request, response) -> {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
});

post("/scene", (request, response) -> {
    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(uploadDir.toPath(), "", "");
    request.attribute("org.eclipse.jetty.multipartConfig", new MultipartConfigElement("/temp"));
    try (InputStream is = request.raw().getPart("uploaded_file").getInputStream()) {
        Files.copy(is, tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        DAOIntf dao = new DAO(tempFile.toAbsolutePath().toString(),"map.xml");
        Scene scene = dao.getXmlScene();
        return new Gson().toJson(scene);
    }catch (Exception e){
        return e;
    }
});
```

By using fetch from a React app like this:

```
  handleFileChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let fileInput = document.getElementsByName("uploaded_file")[0];
    fetch(apiAddress, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: fileInput.files[0]
    }).then( (res) => {
        return res.json()
      }).then( (res)  => {
        this.props.onFileChange(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
  }
```

I know the API is working because i tried it with a simple form in plain html. So I'm guessing the problem is related with how I build the payload.

The way it is I'm getting a 404 and this message at the server logs:

> INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/scene] has not been mapped in Spark

This is the package I'm sending

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4567
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
```

--UPDATE--
Im using this component to activate the call:

```
render(){   return (
    <form>
     <input type='file' name='uploaded_file'  ref={input => {
            this.fileInput = input;
          }}/>
     <button onClick={this.handleFileChange}>Upload</button>    </form>   ) }
```

If I use it with out selecting a file, I get a OK 200 and a `javax.servlet.ServletException: Content-Type != multipart/form-data` exception in the server. So the communication is effective. Still don't now what IS the problem tho.

Comment: If the `/scene` route handler is called when using curl but isn't called when using react's fetch, it means that it *is mapped* correctly, but you're sending the post request differently. So I'd try to understand how it's different (headers etc).

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken, It did not work with curl.